# How to make Gnome Nautilus sort files in lexicographic order?

Tags: linux, gnome, sort, pdf, nautilus

I have three pdf files in a folder. They are named `01.pdf`, `1.pdf` and `2.pdf` respectively. When I click `Name` on the GUI to sort the files by name in ascending order they are sorted `1.pdf, 01.pdf, 2.pdf`. Instead of some weird algorithm I want it to simply sort lexicographically, so that `01.pdf` comes before `1.pdf`. How can I modify its behavior?